What is the error NET MAUI App Project Creation?
Upon creating a .NET MAUI App project, I encountered multiple errors as soon as the project loaded. These issues are pervasive throughout the entire project. Here are a few examples from MainPage.xaml:
MainPage.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Do_Not_Disturb__.MainPage">

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Padding="30,0"
            Spacing="25">
            <Image
                Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                HeightRequest="185"
                Aspect="AspectFit"
                SemanticProperties.Description="dot net bot in a race car number eight" />

            <Label
                Text="Hello, World!"
                Style="{StaticResource Headline}"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1" />

            <Label
                Text="Welcome to &#10;.NET Multi-platform App UI"
                Style="{StaticResource SubHeadline}"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level2"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Welcome to dot net Multi platform App U I" />

            <Button
                x:Name="CounterBtn"
                Text="Click me" 
                SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
                Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
                HorizontalOptions="Fill" />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>

Errors
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   XLS0414 The type 'Button' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.  Do Not Disturb +    C:\Users\apcoa\source\repos\Do Not Disturb +\Do Not Disturb +\MainPage.xaml 27      
Error   MSB4018 The "ResolvePackageAssets" task failed unexpectedly.
NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackagingException: Unable to find fallback package folder 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\NuGetPackages'.
   at NuGet.Packaging.FallbackPackagePathResolver..ctor(String userPackageFolder, IEnumerable`1 fallbackPackageFolders)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.NuGetPackageResolver.CreateResolver(IEnumerable`1 packageFolders)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheWriter..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader.CreateReaderFromDisk(ResolvePackageAssets task, Byte[] settingsHash)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ReadItemGroups()
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ExecuteCore()
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() Do Not Disturb +    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets    266     
Error   MSB4018 The "ResolvePackageAssets" task failed unexpectedly.
NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackagingException: Unable to find fallback package folder 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\NuGetPackages'.
   at NuGet.Packaging.FallbackPackagePathResolver..ctor(String userPackageFolder, IEnumerable`1 fallbackPackageFolders)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.NuGetPackageResolver.CreateResolver(IEnumerable`1 packageFolders)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheWriter..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader.CreateReaderFromDisk(ResolvePackageAssets task, Byte[] settingsHash)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ReadItemGroups()
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ExecuteCore()
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() Do Not Disturb +    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets    266     
Error   MSB4018 The "ResolvePackageAssets" task failed unexpectedly.
NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackagingException: Unable to find fallback package folder 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\NuGetPackages'.
   at NuGet.Packaging.FallbackPackagePathResolver..ctor(String userPackageFolder, IEnumerable`1 fallbackPackageFolders)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.NuGetPackageResolver.CreateResolver(IEnumerable`1 packageFolders)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheWriter..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader.CreateReaderFromDisk(ResolvePackageAssets task, Byte[] settingsHash)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ReadItemGroups()
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ExecuteCore()
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() Do Not Disturb +    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets    266     
Error   MSB4018 The "ResolvePackageAssets" task failed unexpectedly.
NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackagingException: Unable to find fallback package folder 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\NuGetPackages'.
   at NuGet.Packaging.FallbackPackagePathResolver..ctor(String userPackageFolder, IEnumerable`1 fallbackPackageFolders)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.NuGetPackageResolver.CreateResolver(IEnumerable`1 packageFolders)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheWriter..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader.CreateReaderFromDisk(ResolvePackageAssets task, Byte[] settingsHash)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ReadItemGroups()
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ExecuteCore()
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() Do Not Disturb +    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets    266     
Error   XA1018  Specified AndroidManifest file does not exist: C:\Users\apcoa\source\repos\Do Not Disturb +\Do Not Disturb +\AndroidManifest.xml.   Do Not Disturb +    C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.52\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets    596     
Error   XLS0414 The type 'ContentPage' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built. Do Not Disturb +    C:\Users\apcoa\source\repos\Do Not Disturb +\Do Not Disturb +\MainPage.xaml 2       
Error   XLS0414 The type 'ScrollView' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.  Do Not Disturb +    C:\Users\apcoa\source\repos\Do Not Disturb +\Do Not Disturb +\MainPage.xaml 6       
Error   XLS0414 The type 'VerticalStackLayout' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built. Do Not Disturb +    C:\Users\apcoa\source\repos\Do Not Disturb +\Do Not Disturb +\MainPage.xaml 7       
Error   XLS0414 The type 'Image' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.   Do Not Disturb +    C:\Users\apcoa\source\repos\Do Not Disturb +\Do Not Disturb +\MainPage.xaml 10      
Error   XLS0414 The type 'Label' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.   Do Not Disturb +    C:\Users\apcoa\source\repos\Do Not Disturb +\Do Not Disturb +\MainPage.xaml 16      
Error   XLS0414 The type 'Label' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.   Do Not Disturb +    C:\Users\apcoa\source\repos\Do Not Disturb +\Do Not Disturb +\MainPage.xaml 21      


MAUIProgram.cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Do_Not_Disturb__
{
    public static class MauiProgram
    {
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                });

#if DEBUG
            builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

            return builder.Build();
        }
    }
}


Errors
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   CS0103  The name 'MauiApp' does not exist in the current context    Do Not Disturb + (net8.0-ios), Do Not Disturb + (net8.0-maccatalyst), Do Not Disturb + (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0) C:\Users\apcoa\source\repos\Do Not Disturb +\Do Not Disturb +\MauiProgram.cs    9   Active  
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Extensions' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    Do Not Disturb + (net8.0-ios), Do Not Disturb + (net8.0-maccatalyst), Do Not Disturb + (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0) C:\Users\apcoa\source\repos\Do Not Disturb +\Do Not Disturb +\MauiProgram.cs    1   Active  
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'MauiApp' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   Do Not Disturb + (net8.0-ios), Do Not Disturb + (net8.0-maccatalyst), Do Not Disturb + (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0) C:\Users\apcoa\source\repos\Do Not Disturb +\Do Not Disturb +\MauiProgram.cs    7   Active  
Error   MSB4018 The "ResolvePackageAssets" task failed unexpectedly.
NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackagingException: Unable to find fallback package folder 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\NuGetPackages'.
   at NuGet.Packaging.FallbackPackagePathResolver..ctor(String userPackageFolder, IEnumerable`1 fallbackPackageFolders)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.NuGetPackageResolver.CreateResolver(IEnumerable`1 packageFolders)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheWriter..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader.CreateReaderFromDisk(ResolvePackageAssets task, Byte[] settingsHash)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ReadItemGroups()
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ExecuteCore()
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() Do Not Disturb +    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets    266     
Error   MSB4018 The "ResolvePackageAssets" task failed unexpectedly.
NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackagingException: Unable to find fallback package folder 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\NuGetPackages'.
   at NuGet.Packaging.FallbackPackagePathResolver..ctor(String userPackageFolder, IEnumerable`1 fallbackPackageFolders)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.NuGetPackageResolver.CreateResolver(IEnumerable`1 packageFolders)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheWriter..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader.CreateReaderFromDisk(ResolvePackageAssets task, Byte[] settingsHash)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ReadItemGroups()
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ExecuteCore()
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() Do Not Disturb +    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets    266     
Error   MSB4018 The "ResolvePackageAssets" task failed unexpectedly.
NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackagingException: Unable to find fallback package folder 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\NuGetPackages'.
   at NuGet.Packaging.FallbackPackagePathResolver..ctor(String userPackageFolder, IEnumerable`1 fallbackPackageFolders)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.NuGetPackageResolver.CreateResolver(IEnumerable`1 packageFolders)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheWriter..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader.CreateReaderFromDisk(ResolvePackageAssets task, Byte[] settingsHash)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ReadItemGroups()
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ExecuteCore()
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() Do Not Disturb +    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets    266     
Error   MSB4018 The "ResolvePackageAssets" task failed unexpectedly.
NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackagingException: Unable to find fallback package folder 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\NuGetPackages'.
   at NuGet.Packaging.FallbackPackagePathResolver..ctor(String userPackageFolder, IEnumerable`1 fallbackPackageFolders)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.NuGetPackageResolver.CreateResolver(IEnumerable`1 packageFolders)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheWriter..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader.CreateReaderFromDisk(ResolvePackageAssets task, Byte[] settingsHash)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ReadItemGroups()
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ExecuteCore()
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() Do Not Disturb +    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets    266     
Error   XA1018  Specified AndroidManifest file does not exist: C:\Users\apcoa\source\repos\Do Not Disturb +\Do Not Disturb +\AndroidManifest.xml.   Do Not Disturb +    C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.52\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets    596     
Error   XLS0414 The type 'ContentPage' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built. Do Not Disturb +    C:\Users\apcoa\source\repos\Do Not Disturb +\Do Not Disturb +\MainPage.xaml 2       
Error   XLS0414 The type 'ScrollView' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.  Do Not Disturb +    C:\Users\apcoa\source\repos\Do Not Disturb +\Do Not Disturb +\MainPage.xaml 6       
Error   XLS0414 The type 'VerticalStackLayout' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built. Do Not Disturb +    C:\Users\apcoa\source\repos\Do Not Disturb +\Do Not Disturb +\MainPage.xaml 7       
Error   XLS0414 The type 'Image' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.   Do Not Disturb +    C:\Users\apcoa\source\repos\Do Not Disturb +\Do Not Disturb +\MainPage.xaml 10      
Error   XLS0414 The type 'Label' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.   Do Not Disturb +    C:\Users\apcoa\source\repos\Do Not Disturb +\Do Not Disturb +\MainPage.xaml 16      
Error   XLS0414 The type 'Label' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.   Do Not Disturb +    C:\Users\apcoa\source\repos\Do Not Disturb +\Do Not Disturb +\MainPage.xaml 21      
Error   XLS0414 The type 'Button' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.  Do Not Disturb +    C:\Users\apcoa\source\repos\Do Not Disturb +\Do Not Disturb +\MainPage.xaml 27      

I've tried the following troubleshooting steps without success:

Checked the NuGet packages
Reset the NuGet cache
Update NuGet Packages
Restarted Visual Studio
Recreated the project

To be frank, I don't know much about MAUI since this is my first time using it, but I'm pretty sure I shouldn't be encountering errors right off the bat. Has anyone else faced similar issues? Am I missing something?
enter image description here

1.May I know what's the version of VS you are using and also what nuget packages you've installed? 2. What platform your are targeting when the error exists, Android, iOS or Windows?

Your NuGet packages need to get restored

According to the error log you provided, you've changed the default locations(like C:\Program Files (x86)\) for the paths of the nuget packages to D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\NuGetPackages. You can check the two paths: D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\ and D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages and then copy the file referring to this answer.
Also, you can refer to how to the visual studio's nuget package's source. You can set the path as C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages.
Lastly, you can post it on Developer Community since it's a VS issue. This can be done by Visual Studio's "Report a Problem" menu and then follow them on the developer community site. Please see How to report a problem with Visual Studio - Visual Studio | Microsoft Learn
